# How to get SharePoint List Data in a Custom Skill bot

Tags: typescript, sharepoint, botframework

In my custom skill for a virtual assistant (created using botframework v4 template)I need to get data from a SharePoint list

First I created a custom skill with .NET core skill template and tried to get sharepoint list using CSOM, but Support for .NET Core with CSOM API Nuget packages is yet to release (https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/16585795-support-net-core-with-csom)

Now I'm trying to create a skill bot with typescript skill template and connect to sharepoint using SPHttpClient. I'm new to to typescript, and don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, this thing's been "in development" for a crazy long time, especially considering it's just calling REST endpoints!

In the meantime, there's a workaround that might work for you as well - you can use the "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Portable.dll", and I think the copy inside here should be fine: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM/